# How to write a regular expression

Tags: regex

I want to write a expression in this format two alphabet and 3 digit eg. TT234

```
([A-Z]2+[0-9]+)
```

Above was what I wrote but I am getting error. Can anyone comment on it?

Let me rewrite my problem, basically I am writing a rewrite url parameter constraint in .htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On # Turn on the rewriting engine 
RewriteRule ^test/(home|member|admin)/([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})/(xml|json)$ localhost/username/index.php?type=$1&id=$2&format=$3 [L] 
RewriteRule ^test/.*$ localhost/username/error.php [L]
```

And now I am getting this error `xmlParseEntityRef: no name` after I changed the regex expression to `([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})` although it does check the param correctly.

Comment: What are you writing the regex for?? There are many different kinds and literally whole books on them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex is matching for one uppercase ASCII letter, one or more "2" followed by at least one digit.

E.g.:

> - A2123456788990
> - Z20

- If you want to specify exactly 2 letters, then you should not use the quantifier `+`, you can use `{2}`.
- If you write a "2", then it matches a literal "2"
- The same for the digits, if you want to match 3 digits, write a `{3}` instead of `+`
- Depending on your flavour and the method you are calling you need also to **Anchor** your regex, otherwise you will get partial matches.

  You can do this either with `^` and `$` for the start and the end of the string, when your text consists only of this string

  ```
  ^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$
  ```

  If you want to find this pattern in a larger string, then use **Wordboundaries**

  ```
  \b[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}\b
  ```

Comment: It still won't work now go error page RewriteRule  ^/(^[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}$)/(xml|json)

Comment: @user236501, no you already have the anchors, then don't use the ones I wrote in my solution, I assumed, that was the complete pattern. It seems that you want to match file extensions with `(xml|json)`, but you don't match the filename before the extension. try `^/([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})/[^./]+(xml|json)$`

Comment: Hi, I still having the error I rewrite it to :RewriteEngine On    # Turn on the rewriting engine
RewriteRule    ^test/(home|member|admin)/([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})/(xml|json)$    http://localhost/username/index.php?type=$1&id=$2&format=$3  [L]
RewriteRule    ^test/.*$   http://localhost/username/error.php  [L]

Answer (score 1):

There are different syntaxes of regular expressions.  Here is how to do what you need in POSIX Expended Regular Expresions:

```
[A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try like this:

```
([A-Z]{2}[0-9]{3})
```